# What happens after a provisional patent expires?

Tags: patent-applications, expired-patent

I was thinking about applying for a provisional patent and seeking funding for to build my prototyped design on a larger scale.

Should funding fall through or there's not much of a market interest, what happens to my provisional patent?

Does it become public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, just a quick clarification, there is no such thing as a provisional *patent*, but rather a provisional *patent application*. It's a slight difference, but an important one. A provisional doesn't give you any direct protection apart from securing a "priority date".

To answer your question, though, no, the provisional application will be made public **if and only if** you proceed to file a non-provisional application and claim the filing date of the provisional. Of course, this typically isn't a big deal since the non-provisional is often a more smoothed out version by that point anyway, and it will be published according to the schedule you select, or at the eighteen-month mark by default.

If you don't file a non-provisional that claims the original provisional, nothing will happen with it, and it will essentially just disappear.

Answer (score 0):

A quick note, you might not be aware-the filing of your patent application does not require a prototype. You only have to be able to describe it such that one of ordinary skill in the art would understand enough to be able to build it.

Comment: Thanks Harvard. I tried to upvote but don't have enough points yet. Good point.